# Unique value in array using mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database of the students I have a collection in which I only want to insert unique values in my array. My schema looks like this:

```
var classSchema = Schema({
  class: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  name : { type : String },
  ...
  students: [{
    name: String,
    dob: { type: Date, unique: true, sparse: true, required: true }
  }]
});
```

> I want the dob to be unique. When I create new students I am able to create them with the same dob. This is how I am adding it into the database:

```
{$addToSet:
      {
        "students": {
          name: data.name,
          dob: data.dob
        }
      }
    }, {upsert: true}, function(...) ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Unique index not working!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535610/mongoose-unique-index-not-working)

Comment: A unique index won't help you here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo