# insert embedded document in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mlab

I am trying to insert embedded document in MongoDB through nodejs. This is schema of embedded document

```
var patientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: {type: String},
    message:{type: String},
    statusCode:{type: Number},
    user: [{
        pname: {type : String },
        email: {type : String },
        password: {type : String },
        mobile: {type : String},
        otp:{type: Number},
        age: {type : String }
    }]
})
```

and here is the code of insertion

```
router.post('/panel/register', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.mobile_number+req.body.email);
        new patient({
            status: "ok",
            message:"success",
            statusCode:"201",
            'user.$.pname': req.body.name,
            'user.$.password': req.body.password,
            'user.$.email': req.body.email,
            'user.$.mobile': req.body.mobile_number
        }).save(function(err, doc){
            if(err) res.json(err);
            else {
                    res.json({"doc ":doc});
            }
        })
    })
```

but whenever i am trying to insert data using this code it is showing me this error

```
{
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 0,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error index: rhc.patients.$mobile_1 dup key: { : null }",
    "op": {
        "status": "ok",
        "message": "success",
        "statusCode": 201,
        "_id": "59f38e4d94fff613fc8c4979",
        "user": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

As i am understanding this error is because this is not mapping the values of email, mobile inside the user, can someone help to resolve it, i think i am inserting it in wrong way , please help

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

For clarity: the problem wasn't really the syntax, but rather a unique constraint that was removed, without the database being updated. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535610/mongoose-unique-index-not-working).

**Original answer:**

You can do it like this:

```
router.post('/panel/register', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.mobile_number+req.body.email);
        new patient({
            status: "ok",
            message:"success",
            statusCode:"201",
            user: [{
                pname: req.body.name,
                password: req.body.password,
                email: req.body.email,
                mobile: req.body.mobile_number
            }]
        }).save(function(err, doc){
            if(err) res.json(err);
            else {
                    res.json({"doc ":doc});
            }
        })
    })
```

This will create a user object in the user array. Are you sure it's supposed to be an array on not just an object? Remove [] from both the model and controller to make it an ordinary object.

Comment: I am still getting same error after the changes that you are suggesting, yes i am sure it's supposed to be an array

Comment: Has the mobile field ever had the unique constraint? Or any of the other fields? If you are developing on a test database you can try dropping the patient collection, restarting mongod and your app. Add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` for good measure and make sure that the index is created when you start the app.